# This recaptcha is for testing purposes only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

I'm doing `recaptcha` integration and I encountered the error as in the ss below.

[image]

Can you help with the solution?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We are clearly missing some crucial informations here. What are you working on ? Wordpress ? Drupal ? Something else ? In which language ? Which library ?

Comment: asp.net mvc project , c#

Comment: Looks like you need to logon to the google api captcha console and check the site settings https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin looks llike a mis configuration

Comment: thank you . I'm looking at .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, from a quick Google the key you are using (v3 key) is set up for testing purposes only.

> I'd like to run automated tests with reCAPTCHA. What should I do? For
>   reCAPTCHA v3, create a separate key for testing environments. Scores
>   may not be accurate as reCAPTCHA v3 relies on seeing real traffic.
>
> For reCAPTCHA v2, use the following test keys. You will always get No
>   CAPTCHA and all verification requests will pass.
>
> The reCAPTCHA widget will show a warning message to ensure it's not
>   used for production traffic.

Source https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq

Simply create a new key that is for live environments.

Comment: how do you setup for testing.  I see this in the faq but don't see anywhere on the recaptcha setup page for setting it as a testing key.

For reCAPTCHA v3, create a separate key for testing environments. Scores may not be accurate as reCAPTCHA v3 relies on seeing real traffic.